# Software Updater crashes in 12.10 beta2

Tags: updates, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve “Failed to download repository information”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141512/how-to-resolve-failed-to-download-repository-information)

I try to update from Ubuntu 12.10 beta2 to 12.10, using the Software Updater, but it tells me every time, I try to load the program, that it *"failed to download repository information"*.

What should I do, to get the Software Updater running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try different download Server and/or change your repository settings. See...

[Update Manager failed to download repository, 401 error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170076/update-manager-failed-to-download-repository-401-error/170082#170082)

[How to resolve "Failed to download repository information"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141512/how-to-resolve-failed-to-download-repository-information)

...for the basic idea. It might or might not help depending on what is wrong with your repository information. In the meantime try to investigate further by looking at the error logs and posting them here (edit your question to contain the logs).