# Managing Kile installation in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, software-center, kile

After installing  12.04 Ubuntu I tried to install Kile  but when I was trying to install Kile , it showed that "failed to download package file . Check your internet connections" . But my INTERNET is working properly even I can download updates available . How can I solve this problem ?

Still trying to install it but it says " Failed to download package files .Check your Internet connection. ,
Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/virtuoso-opensource/virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin_6.1.4+dfsg1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb Size mismatch "

There is no problem in INTERNET browsing so where is the problem ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Manager failed to download repository, 401 error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170076/update-manager-failed-to-download-repository-401-error)

Comment: Most likely a broken PPA, it's looking for a CDROM, or some other repository configuration problem.  You'd need to tell us what the errors are exactly.  Have a look at this example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170076/update-manager-failed-to-download-repository-401-error

Comment: http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/virtuoso-opensource/virtuoso-opensource6.1-bin_6.1.4+dfsg1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  . this link is showing when i try to install .

Comment: Can you fetch it in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem while trying to get a system image ready for next semester.

I got the same errors when I tried to use the Ubuntu software center.

So I opened a terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install kile`.
This also had errors, so I ran this command, `sudo apt-get update`, in the terminal.

After the updates I was able to run the first command but modified it to this, `sudo apt-get install kile --fix-missing`.

At this time, it is still running as latex takes a while to install, but it seems to be working.